# Unable to read same message on same topic by multiple consumers

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am publishing a message to `topicX`. To consume this message by multiple consumers, I have written following `ConsumerConfig` (Note, each consumer has different `groupd_id`.

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my.groupid." + groupId);
        props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Car> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(groupId), new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Car.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Car> consumerOneKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Car> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory("one"));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Car> consumerTwoKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Car> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory("two"));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And then on specific consumer, I have added following annotation (specified the group id and container factory)

`@KafkaListener(id = "my.groupid.one", topics = "${app.topic.topicname}", containerFactory = "consumerOneKafkaListenerContainerFactory")`

But when i publish the message, only one consumer consumes it. How can i i configure kafka so that each published message is consumed by multiple consumers?

I have tried this code with 1 partition and *n* partitions (where n = number of consumers) and yet i am having this issue.

**UPDATE**

Here is my topic producer class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class TopicProducer {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, TopicPayload> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String topicName, TopicPayload payload) {
        log.info("sending message={} to topic={}", payload, topicName);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, payload);
    }

}
```

And here is my TopicProducerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class TopicProducerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, TopicPayload> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, TopicPayload> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

I post a message by calling `producer.send(topicName, payload)`.

Comment: Are you using keyed producer ? Are you producing different types of msgs which yields different hash/key?

Comment: Let me update the question how i am producing the msg.

Comment: I don't see you have two instances of consumer factories there. Could u just create separate config classes for 2 consumers , including separate consumer factory.